# How communicate two remote machine through ansible

Tags: ansible

I am running ansible playbook from system 1 which runs tasks on system 2 to take backup and after that, I want to copy backup file from system 2 to system 3.

I am doing this task for automating below command
where /bck1/test on system 2 and opt/backup on system 3

```
rsync -r -v -e ssh /bck1/test.* root@host3:/opt/backup
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You can execute the `rsync` task through Ansible on host 2 with the [shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html). I don't recommend to use the [synchronize module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) as you would first have to download the backup to system 1 before uploading it to system 3.

Comment: My question is how do i copy backup file from system 2 to system 3 using rsync command without copy it on system 1? as i am running ansible from system 1 i don't want to use it for backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the raw rsync command with the `shell` module.

```
tasks:
  - shell: rsync -r -v -e ssh /bck1/test.* root@host3:/opt/backup
```

For this to work, you will either need to have your private ssh key deployed to system 2, or, preferable enable ssh agent forwarding, for example in your `.ssh/config`:

```
Host host2
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Additionally sshd on system 2 would need to accept agent forwarding. Here are some tasks which I use to do this:

```
- name: Ensure sshd allows agent forwarding
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config
              regexp=^#?AllowAgentForwarding
              line="AllowAgentForwarding yes"
              follow=yes
              backup=yes
  sudo: yes
  register: changed_sshd_config

- name: "Debian: Restart sshd"
  shell: invoke-rc.d ssh restart
  sudo: yes
  when:
    - ansible_distribution in [ "Debian", "Ubuntu" ]
    - changed_sshd_config | changed

- name: "CentOS 7: Restart sshd"
  shell: systemctl restart sshd.service
  sudo: yes
  when:
    - ansible_distribution == "CentOS"
    - ansible_distribution_major_version == "7"
    - changed_sshd_config | changed
```

There are two separate tasks for restarting sshd on Debian and CentOS7. Pick what you need or maybe you have to adapt that to your system.

You might need to configure this in a separate playbook. Because Ansible will keep an open ssh connection to the host and after activating agent forwarding you most probably will need to re-connect.

PS: It's not the best idea to allow ssh login for user root, but that is another topic. :)

Comment: No it's not configured

Comment: I added the tasks I use for enabling agent forwarding.

Comment: I am using linux and i am new to ansible is there any another way to automate     rsync -r -v -e ssh  /bck1/test.*   root@host3:/opt/backup

Comment: where i am running role from system 1 which take backup on system 2 and want to use rysync command to copy backup file from system 2 to system 3 but using same role

Comment: To copy the files from system 2 to system 3 you need to be able to log in from system 2 to 3. Any possible solution can not circumvent this. You can  place your private key on system 2 (which is not recommended) or work with agent forwarding as described above. In the simplest case, activate agent forwarding manually without Ansible and see how far you come. (just guessing agent forwarding is the problem you're having with described solution)