# How to copy file from host2 to host3 assuming ansible was run on host1

Tags: ansible

I have ansible installed on host1. There is file on host2 which I need to copy on host3 by ansible. I am using RHEL.

I have following yml running on host2 but its getting stuck at copy file task.

```
- name: Ensure sshd allows agent forwarding
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config
              regexp=^#?AllowAgentForwarding
              line="AllowAgentForwarding yes"
              follow=yes
              backup=yes
  sudo: yes
  register: changed_sshd_config

- name: "RHEL: Restart sshd"
  shell: /etc/init.d/sshd restart
  sudo: yes
  when:
    - changed_sshd_config | changed

- name: Copy file from host2 to host3
  shell: rsync -r -v -e ssh /root/samplefile.gz root@host3:/root
```

Can anyone explain me what is missing here. If you can, Please provide details steps mentioning correct hosts.

Comment: Can you send the file to the host1 and then from there to host3? Or if the file is to big send it to let's say `AWS S3` and then copy it from host3?

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely is you can not log in from host2 to host3 and Ansible is hanging at this task because rsync is waiting for you to enter the ssh password. Are you able to log in manually from host2 to host3?

I answered the same question before in [How communicate two remote machine through ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31823536/2753241) (can't flag as duplicate because no answer was accepted...)

The following is a slightly modified version of the linked answer. The tasks were written for CentOS, so it should work on RHEL.

---

For this to work, you will either need to have your private ssh key deployed to host2, or, preferable enable ssh agent forwarding, for example in your `.ssh/config`:

```
Host host2
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Additionally sshd on host2 would need to accept agent forwarding. Here are some tasks which I use to do this:

```
- name: Ensure sshd allows agent forwarding
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config
              regexp=^#?AllowAgentForwarding
              line="AllowAgentForwarding yes"
              follow=yes
              backup=yes
  sudo: yes
  register: changed_sshd_config

- name: "Restart sshd"
  shell: systemctl restart sshd.service
  sudo: yes
  when: changed_sshd_config | changed
```

You might need to configure this in a separate playbook. Because Ansible might keep an open ssh connection to the host and after activating agent forwarding you probably will need to re-connect.

Comment: Rsync may also be hanging in host key checking which you can bypass by adding  `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to ssh command line.